# Class cannot be converted to a a string

Tags: java

Title sounds stupid but hear me out

I'm trying to write a program that creates a car (make, model, year of production and odometer) and when I try to add a car to the list array I get the following error:

"incompatible types: Car cannot be converted to String"

Does anyone know a way around this/a way to fix this

any help will be appreciated, my code is below (**Also, I can't remove the ArrayList aspect of the program**).

```
public class Car {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    String make, model, year, odometer; 
    int ptr = 0;

    public Car(String year, String odometer, String make, String model) 
    { 
        this.make = make; 
        this.model = model; 
        this.year = year; 
        this.odometer = odometer; 
    } 

    public String toString() 
    { 
        return this.make + " " + this.model + " " + this.year+ " " + this.odometer; 
    } 

    public void carAdd(){
        System.out.println("What is the make of the car?");
        String newMake = scan.next();
        System.out.println("What is the model of the car?");
        String newModel = scan.next();
        System.out.println("What year was the car produced?");
        String newYear = scan.next();
        System.out.println("How far has this car traveled?");
        String newOdometer = scan.next();
        cars.add(new Car(newMake, newModel, newYear, newOdometer));
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple, change `ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();` to `ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();`. Makes no sense to create a list of Strings when you're going to want to add Car objects to it.

Comment: Why does your `Car` class contains a `List` of cars?  Separate the `Car` from the logic of inputting (and storing a List of) Cars.  Then decide whether you want a List of Cars or a List of Car names.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thank you for the help

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `may attract down-votes` ... too late, it seems :-(

Answer (score 1):

You should be populating a list of cars, not of string:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
```

That being said, if you really wanted to maintain a list of string representations of `Car` objects, then you could populate your current string list using `Car#toString`:

```
public void carAdd(){
    System.out.println("What is the make of the car?");
    String newMake = scan.next();
    System.out.println("What is the model of the car?");
    String newModel = scan.next();
    System.out.println("What year was the car produced?");
    String newYear = scan.next();
    System.out.println("How far has this car traveled?");
    String newOdometer = scan.next();
    cars.add(new Car(newMake, newModel, newYear, newOdometer).toString());
}
```

You typically would not do this, as the string version of the `Car` can easily be gotten by calling `Car#toString`.  Using a stream, you might try:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
// populate list
List<String> carStrings = cars.stream()
    .map(c -> c.toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
```

creates a list of strings instead of cars. For that you must use:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>()
```